# After installing curl giving Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: ubuntu, curl, php-5.6

Completed following step ..
1) sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
2) sudo service apache2 restart

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html_v2/application/controllers/Test.php on line 110
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Filename: controllers/Test.php

Line Number: 110

Backtrace:

Please also find phpinfo() about cUrl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elEr3.png)

Comment: What does phpinfo() say about curl?

Comment: please check the update Q ... I attach phpinfo() screenshot ... there is no any other things about cUrl

Comment: still not solved this issue please help...

Comment: curl may be installed but it doesn't look like the module has loaded in your php.ini file.
This might help, depending on your environment: http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/